# Updated GPS coordinate shows rotated point

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, php

So I have a GPS coordinate:

```
8.6258,47.3325
```

Which I use as my origin. Then I have the path of an object that has been moving around based on the ENU position, say:

```
-10, 12 //east, north in meters
-8, 11
...
```

I want to plot this on a map so I took the GPS coordinate and converted each ENU point to a GPS coordinate I can use on a map, however these coordinates show up rotated on a map, could someone point me in the right direction here?

In order to convert the ENU points I've used the function:

```
function updateCoordsByDistance($lat,$lon,$mNorth,$mEast){
    //Earth’s radius, sphere
    $R = 6378137;

    //Coordinate offsets in radians
    $dLat = $mNorth / $R;
    $dLon = $mEast / ($R * cos(M_PI * $lat / 180));

    //OffsetPosition, decimal degrees
    $latO = $lat + $dLat * 180 / M_PI;
    $lonO = $lon + $dLon * 180 / M_PI;

    return array(latO,$lonO);
}
```

Comment: @Mapperz it's php actually, shouldn't be too different in python

Comment: try a simple conversion http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#flat

Comment: Are you sure you did not mix up East/North or lat/lon in your input?